# Automatic Wifi connection before Windows logon

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, group-policy, 802.1x

Can I force an automatic connection to a specific Wifi network before the logon?
I want to enable my users to connect with their domain credential using the company wifi network during the login. Otherwise they login with cached credentials.
I have already distributed the wifi network preferences with GPO, but the connection is not automatic and the user has to select the network and push "Connect".

I read somewhere that I had to enable SSO before user logon in Wifi GPO, but I have the option greyed and I cannot understand how to enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option was right and I had to change the authentication mode from Computer to User and Computer.

[image]